# Vagrant: How to set default log level for Puppet?

Tags: logging, vagrant, puppet

I use Puppet as provisioner within Vagrant. I'd like to see only "warn" and higher log level output on puppet's console output.

Is it possible to configure the default log level [1] for Puppet in Vagrant to "warn"? Does this affect the console output?

[1] https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/configuration.html#loglevel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant allows you to pass arbitrary options to puppet ([see `options`](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html)). This includes any configuration options puppet has, so you can set `options` to `['--log_level', 'err']`.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no puppet command line option `--log_level`. Typically, `--log_level` is configured in `puppet.conf`.

Your proposal ends in the following error message:
`Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --log_level`

Comment: What version of puppet are you running? The `log_level` configuration setting was added in Puppet 3.6. I don't know of any way to change the log level in previous versions.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for this hint. My puppet version is `3.4.3-1ubuntu1.1` that comes with `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS`. So I should try to upgrade with packages from `apt.puppetlabs.com` I guess...

I'll try something like this:
https://coderwall.com/p/jiabja/automatically-update-puppet-in-your-vagrant-precise64-box

Comment: Here's the relevant change in puppet: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/pull/2413/files